# How do I stop c# program from returning 0 after dividing by larger numbers?

Tags: c#, converters, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I have a program that allows users to input numbers which are divided by another number. It returns 0 when the first number is smaller than 1 or smaller than denominator. 
I know that when dividing by decimals we should add ".0" to convert integers to decimal place. But how do I do it in an assigned variable.

```
static void Main(string args) {

    Console.WriteLine("Enter first number: ");
    double Number1 = double.Parse(Console.Readline());

    Console.WriteLine("Enter second number: ");
    double Number2 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    double result = Number1/Number2 
    Console.WriteLine("{0} divided by {1} is " + {2}, Number1, Number2, result);

}
```

Comment: @EliSadoff You should read the code properly. S/He is using `double.Parse`

Comment: @Vikhram Oh, I misread the code. Sorry.

Comment: @Jane this code doesn't even compile

Answer (score 1):

The code (logically) seems to be working fine, but what you have posted has bunch of compiler errors. I tried the code below and it worked fine for me

```
static void Main(string []args) {

    Console.WriteLine("Enter first number: ");
    var Number1 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Enter second number: ");
    var Number2 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    double result = Number1 / Number2;

    Console.WriteLine("{0} divided by {1} is {2}", Number1, Number2, result);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add suffix when using constant expressions to specify type of constant.
not any suffix needed when you specified the variable type in the declare statement.